# JSF . SelectOneMenu and SelectItems

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I'm trying to let user select an item of a collection from a dropdown list in JSF.
This is the code I'm using:

```
<f:view>
 <h:form id="insert">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyBean.user}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.userList}" var="currentUser" itemValue="#{currentUser.username}" itemLabel="#{currentUser.username}"/>
     </h:selectOneMenu>
     <h:commandButton value="Insert" action="#{AuctionBean.insertItem}"/><br>
 </h:form>
</f:view>
```

And this is MyBean's code:

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean{
    private String user;
    private Collection<User> userList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
                this.userList = UserRepository.getInstance().findAllUsers();
    }
    ...
    public String insertItem() {
         System.out.println("The selected user is " + this.user);
         ...
         return ("successfulInsertion");
    }
...
}
```

And if needed my getter and setter for user:

```
public String getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

My problem is that when it prints "The selected user is " there's not written the user.toString(), but userList.toString()! It's like the selectOneMenu it's not correctly setted, but I've searched a lot about it.
Anyone can help? Thanks,
AN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<f:selectItems>` doesn't support `Collection`. You need a `List` or `Map` or `Object[]`.

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

---

**Update**: it turns out that you're using JSP instead of Facelets. The new JSF 2.x tags and attributes are **not** available for JSP. This includes the `<f:selectItems var>`. Only the old JSF 1.x tags and attributes are available for JSP. Since JSF 2.0, JSP has been deprecated and succeeded by Facelets. You should be using Facelets instead.

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870)

Comment: So I should make my userList a List (eg LinkedList) to make it work in this way? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Use `ArrayList` as it's faster on retrieval by index.

Comment: It's still not working... 
This is what i receive: 
The user is [User[g.riva, Gigi, Riva, ***, g.riva@abc.com], User[he, asd, adsdas, **, asdasd], User[mario.rossi, Mario, Rossi, ***, mario.rossi@gmail.com], User[paolo.bianchi, Paolo, Bianchi, ***, paolo.bianchi@hotmail.it]].

Comment: I changed the type of userList in ArrayList<User> and filled it in this way:

this.userList = new ArrayList<User>(UserRepository.getInstance().findAllUsers());

Comment: I don't know if i'm making any sort of mistake... Thanks, AN

Comment: As per the comments on the other answer you seem to be still using legacy JSP while using JSF 2.0. This is not right.

Comment: That solved the problem, I made it using JSF 2.0 and it worked. Thanks, AN

Answer (score 1):

Add `<f:ajax/>` to your `<h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyBean.user}">`

like this

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyBean.user}">
    <f:ajax/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.userList}" var="currentUser" itemValue="#{currentUser.username}" itemLabel="#{currentUser.username}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

this will submit your selection to the server each time you will choose a value from the dropdown...

OR

add `<f:ajax execute="@form"/>` to your button so it will submit the selection of your dropdown menu before the call to `insertItem`

```
<h:commandButton value="Insert" action="#{AuctionBean.insertItem}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: add `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"` next to  `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"` in your `xhtml` file

Comment: I've done it: `<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>`